# Printing 2D Matrix file, getting wrong data in MPI c program

Tags: c, file-io, matrix, mpi

```
int fh = open (filename, O_RDONLY);
int **InputBuffer;
InputBuffer = (int **)malloc(rowLocal * sizeof(int));
for (i = 0; i < rowLocal; i++)
{
    InputBuffer[i] = (int*)malloc(clmLocal * sizeof(int));
}
lseek(fh, rowLocal * clmLocal * sizeof(int) * MyRank,SEEK_SET);
for (index = 0; index < rowLocal; index++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < clmLocal; i++)
    {
        int readchk = read (fh,&(InputBuffer[index][i]),sizeof(int));
    }
}

for (index = 0; index < rowLocal; index++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < clmLocal; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d \t",InputBuffer[index][i]);
    }
}
```

Its giving wrong output as:

```
Rank 1 of 2 processes
 6475664     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   End of File for process 1 
Rank 0 of 2 processes
 540614708   540221496   171319349   540287026   540221493   170926129   540483637   540155956   171384881   540352564   540221497   170926130   540614707   540024881   171057205   540352562   540024881   170991670   End of File for process 0
```

Actual File:
cat test
4 9 8 3 5 6
2 4 5 3 1 0
5 7 4 2 1 7
4 5 9 3 2 0
3 9 1 0 5 2
2 5 1 0 6 1

As whole its an MPI C program. Can anyone please help and let me know where am I going wrong.

Solution: read is binary operation does not read text file. Issue solved when tried to read binary file. Thanks every one for your help.

Comment: Thanks for response @HighPerformanceMark. Actually file will be given at command line so not sure about formatting but for sure I will try to format it ..thanks 4 advice. and I am trying to print with file which contain int number like:    cat test
4 9 8 3 5 6
2 4 5 3 1 0
5 7 4 2 1 7
4 5 9 3 2 0
3 9 1 0 5 2
2 5 1 0 6 1

Comment: The issue may be that an ASCII text is prodived as input...and `read()` reads binary data. As quoted [here](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_8.html), **Stream-level I/O is more flexible and usually more convenient; therefore, programmers generally use the descriptor-level functions only when necessary.** You may switch to `stdio.h` [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/). `open` becomes `fopen` and `lseek` becomes `fseek`. If your input is ASCII, maybe `fscanf(pFile,"%d",&(InputBuffer[index][i]));` would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Francis. This helps. Now I am able to print binary file. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: If you think that the solution suggested by @francis is the answer to your question then post it as an answer.  That way you can (after a decent interval) accept the answer and this question will no longer appear in the unanswered question lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be that an ASCII text is prodived as input...and read() reads binary data.

As quoted [here](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_8.html), Stream-level I/O is more flexible and usually more convenient; therefore, programmers generally use the descriptor-level functions only when necessary.

You may switch to stdio.h [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/). open becomes fopen and lseek becomes fseek. If your input is ASCII, maybe `fscanf(pFile,"%d",&(InputBuffer[index][i]));` would do the trick.